# How many times the function will be invoked?

Tags: c, algorithm, complexity-theory

Here i have the loop:

```
for (i = n; i < 2*n; i += 4) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3*i; j += 2) {
        function();
    }
}
```

How can i count amount of calls (in a term of n) of function() without running this code?

As the idea i think i can use arithmetic progression, which has the sum is S = (a1 + ak) * k / 2, where a1 - is amount of iterations of inner loop while i has initial value and ak - is amount of iterations of inner loop while i has final value.

But i cannot express it as a one formula with n as a variable.

Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: if i use O(n) notation - it will be O(n^2). but i need to express accurate formula which will count how many times function() is counted

Comment: Your title isn't particularly meaningful, but I can't say that I can think of a better one.

Comment: @FelixVein You have been posting these homework for a while now and moreover i think this is a mathematical problem then algorithmic

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop performs 3*i/2 calls. The outer loop has i=n, n+4, n+8 .. 2n-4. Therefore we have:

```
count = 3*n/2 + 3*(n+4)/2 + 3*(n+8)/2 + ... 3*2*n/2 =
= 3/2 * (n + (n+4) + (n+8) + .. + (2n-4)) = 
= 3/2 * (3n^2-4n) / 8 =
= (9n^2 - 12n) / 16
```

(Edit: there may still be small inaccuracies that need to be fixed)

Edit #2 - I followed **self**'s correction, and now I get the expected result.

Comment: How did you get `(n^2/4 + (4 + 8 + .. n))` from `(n + (n+4) + (n+8) + .. + 2n)`? Is it `(n^2)/4` or `n^(2/4)`

Comment: You are close but the final numbers are wrong. If you run the code you get different result.

Comment: The actual formula that works if n is divisible by 4 is `(n/4)*((9n/4)-3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've got the formula for arithmetic progression.  When i = n, the inner loop goes 3n/2 times (more or less -- you may have to convert to a whole number).  You may have to tweak the upper end a bit because there's no guarantee that n is divisible by 4, but you can do the same for the final loop.  And it will run n/4 times (again convert to whole number).

Answer (score 0):

Below are the formal steps that would allow you to deduce the exact number of times `function()` would execute:

[image]

The outer loop will execute n + ceil(n/4) - 1 times, the inner loop depends on the outer loop. I tried to detail as much as possible to make this solution clear enough.